# How is defined a domain (/codomain) in Category Theory? As a function, it is a morphism hence has a domain (/codomain). This, infinitely?

Tags: category-theory, morphism

I'm basing myself on the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)) on Categories.
A category $C$ consists on:

- a class of objects $Ob(C)$
- a class of morphism $Mor(C)$
- a class function going from $Mor(C)$ to $Ob(C)$ called domain
- a class function going from $Mor(C)$ to $Ob(C)$ called codomain
- etc

While I don't totally understand the concept of classes (and hence, of class functions), I am yet  faced with this problem: 'domain' and 'codomain' being functions, they must be morphisms. Hence the have a domain and a codomain. But the domain and codomain of these domains and codomains must be again morphisms ; and this goes on and on ?

Comment: They are functions *outside* the category; they are not "morphisms". Essentially, they are either primitive notions (if you are axiomatizing Categories without modelling them), or else they are functions within whatever Set Theory you are using to construct categories.

Comment: $Mor(C)$ and $Ob(C)$ are two classes, and $dom,cod:Mor(C)\to Ob(C)$ are two maps of classes; so $dom$ and $cod$ are not "morphisms" in the sense that they are elements of $Mor(C)$

Comment: Ok! So in the case we are using Set Theory, these functions are from the **Set** category? Is that what you meant by "Set Theory"? Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: The category of Sets is a specific category within the constructed category theory. There is a difference between "the category $\mathsf{Set}$" within whatever model of Category Theory you are doing, and whatever set theory you are using to construct the model of Category Theory that you are using. Basically: you need some "background theory" that works as the foundation of your Category Theory. The category $\mathsf{Set}$ is something *within* Category Theory, and so it cannot function as that "background theory".